# Remove all lines containing one of some numbers

Tags: matlab, optimization, logic

I have a vector `doneS = [1 5 9]` containing certain numbers. Further I have a matrix which could look like this: `matrix = [1 2 6 0 0 9; 8 6 0 0 0 9; 2 2 0 0 5 3]`.
I want to remove all lines of the matrix, where the numbers in columns `1:end-1` contain any number of `doneS`, thus I'll get in this example:
`matrix = [8 6 0 0 0 9]`

I already have the following two solutions to this:

```
for m = doneS
    matrix(any(matrix(:, 1:end-1) == m, 2), :) = [];
end
```

I further did find a faster solution, which first finds all indices to delete and only does the deletion once, which works faster as I tested it:

```
log = any(matrix(:, 1:end-1) == doneS(1), 2);
for m = doneS(2:end)
     log = log | any(matrix(:, 1:end-1) == m, 2);
end
matrix(log, :) = [];
```

But this still takes some time and I'm wondering if there is any faster solution to this?

**EDIT**
Thanks to oli for another approach! Here's a benchmark script:

```
rows = 2e5;
cols = 100;
doneEls = 30;

% Testingdata
doneS = int8(round(100*rand(1, doneEls)));
matrix1 = int8(round(1000*rand(rows, cols)));
matrix2 = matrix1;
matrix3 = matrix1;

tic
log = any(matrix1(:, 1:end-1) == doneS(1), 2);
for m = doneS(2:end)
    log = log | any(matrix1(:, 1:end-1) == m, 2);
end
matrix1(log, :) = [];
t1 = toc

tic
for m = doneS
   matrix2(any(matrix2(:, 1:end-1) == m, 2), :) = [];
end
t2 = toc

tic
matrix3(any(ismember(matrix3(:, 1:end-1), doneS), 2), :) = [];
t3 = toc

isequal(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `ismember`:

```
doneS = [1 5 9]
matrix = [1 2 6 0 0 9; 8 6 0 0 0 9; 2 2 0 0 5 3]

matrix(any(ismember(matrix(:,1:end-1),doneS),2),:)=[]
```

Comment: looks good, thanks. You just missed that I only want to check columns 1:end-1, but it's simple: `matrix(any(ismember(matrix(:,1:end-1),doneS),2),:)=[]`. I'm gonna benchmark it to look if it's faster :)

Comment: Thanks, just tested it out, and it's most of the times faster than the other approaches. It actually depends much on the input data, wether there are many mathces or not. I updated the initial post with a little benchmark script if somebody wants to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `unique` before `ismember` is even faster:

```
t1 =
       1.9354
t2 =
      0.97107
t3 =
       0.2919
t4 =
      0.024983
```

.

```
rows = 2e5;
cols = 100;
doneEls = 30;

% Testingdata
doneS = int8(round(100*rand(1, doneEls)));
matrix1 = int8(round(1000*rand(rows, cols)));
matrix2 = matrix1;
matrix3 = matrix1;

tic
log = any(matrix1(:, 1:end-1) == doneS(1), 2);
for m = doneS(2:end)
    log = log | any(matrix1(:, 1:end-1) == m, 2);
end
matrix1(log, :) = [];
t1 = toc

tic
for m = doneS
   matrix2(any(matrix2(:, 1:end-1) == m, 2), :) = [];
end
t2 = toc

tic
matrix3(any(ismember(matrix3(:, 1:end-1), doneS), 2), :) = [];
t3 = toc


doneSu = unique(doneS);
tic
matrix3(any(ismember(matrix3(:, 1:end-1), doneSu), 2), :) = [];
t4 = toc
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, when you use `unique()`, you could also use it before using the ismember-alternative, and than the ismember one is again faster :-) Actually, I forgot to state, that `doneS` is always unique :) Thus I'll stick with the ismember-alternative!